# Hairy systems of equation on differentiability of piecewise function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I'm having trouble trying to eliminate and solve for variables that satisfy continuity in a piecewise defined function.  The asks for a value of $a$, $b$, and $c$ where the below function is differentiable everywhere.  Here the function:

$$
f(x)\left\{\begin{matrix}
\tan ^{-1} x,& x\leq 0\\ 
 ax^2+bx+c,& 0< x<2\\ 
 x^{3}-\frac{1}{4}x^{2}+5,& x\geq 2
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

Realizing that a line is continuously differentiable at:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=f'(0)
$$

I set the two rightmost defined functions equal to each other:

$$ax^2+bx+c=x^{3}-\frac{1}{4}x^{2}+5$$

and substituted $x=2$:

$$4a+2b+c = 12$$

Then I repeated that process, but this time I substituted $x=2$ into the *derivatives* of the rightmost equations to get:

$$
4a+b=13
$$

The answer, I know, has to be solved from these two systems of equations.  However, I feel like I need $a$, $b$, or $c$ to appear at in at least one other equation.  How can I begin to solve for these variables?

Comment: The question requires values for $a$, $b$, and $c$ that make this function differentiable everywhere

Comment: Sorry I was trying to edit my comment and it deleted it, I was going to add that you also should use the left point at zero to constrain c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are nearly there! It's just that for differentiability everywhere, this function must also be continuous and differentiable at x=0, so do the same with the $\tan^{-1}x$ at $0$ as you did at x=2 with the polynomial functions.

For continuity at $x=0$, $tan^{-1}0=a(0)^2+b(0)+c$

$$\implies c=0$$ I'm sure you can continue.

Comment: I did this, and found $c=0$, $b=-1$, $a=\frac{14}{4}$.  But when I graph this, the functions don't appear to exactly touch each other at the stated x points.  Hmm...

Comment: Yes there is some mistake, because you see if you imply differentiability at 0, you will get another equation, and by this you will have 4 equations ( 2 of continuity and 2 of differentiability) and 3 variables and the system is inconsistent

Comment: The problem seems overly constrained, that is C must be zero, its the only way to match the arctangent, but this yields three equations in the variables a and b, with the one at zero requiring that b equal 1...as such a cannot be chosen to satisfy both equations unless you sacrifice differentiability

Comment: Can I prove analytically that a solution of $a$, $b$, and $c$ doesn't exist by showing how I solved for $c$ and demonstrate an inequality in either $b$ or $a$?

Comment: Yes you can get c=0, and then can put it in other equations you get (you will get 3 of them) and show that no pair of a,b simultaneously satisfies all 3 equations, therefore there exist no a,b,c for which this happens